# Drag-and-Drop GridPanel rows in Coolite

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, extjs, coolite

[Coolite](http://www.coolite.com/) has [excellent support](http://examples.coolite.com/?/GridPanel/Commands/Cell_Command/) for Grids, and the GridPanel control has an obvious property: [EnableDragDrop](http://docs.coolite.com/Coolite.Ext.Web~Coolite.Ext.Web.GridPanelBase~EnableDragDrop.html).  But after a lengthy search through the forums and given examples, I have yet to come across a good example that demonstrates a fairly simple task: **drag-and-drop rearranging of rows in a normal GridPanel**.

Has anyone implemented drag-and-drop of GridPanel rows in Coolite without resorting to working directly with Ext JS?

---

**Edit**:

- @Kheu: I have indeed tried setting `EnableDragDrop="true"` on a Coolite `ext:GridPanel`.  But that is just part of the equation.  Just setting `EnableDragDrop="true"` will give you the ability to drag rows (well, kind of; a simple "n row(s) selected" placeholder appears) but disallow you from dropping them.  I’ve managed to enable drag and drop by augmenting the Coolite controls with plain ExtJS, but I am hesitant to post my work, because it seems there should be a simple solution in Coolite.  There is even a good [multiselect drag-and-drop example](http://examples.coolite.com/?/Form/MultiSelect/Overview/) (see the "Drag/Drop (Insert Mode)" tab, but with no clear means of recreating the same functionality in GridPanels (that example uses `ext:Multiselect` nested within a regular `ext:Panel`).

Comment: I developed several projects with coolite but i never tried the EnableDragDrop. Yet let me get you straight, did you try the EnableDragDrop and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to take a look at how rearranging columns is implemented in ExtJS (quite complicated)? And reimplement it for rows in a similar way.